# Как подключить один и тот же Maildir на несколько почтовых аккаунтов

Tags: dovecot, email

Имеется: /D1/spam/badsender/new/ - каталог который хочется подключить к почтовым ящикам

```
/usr/vmail/domain.su/lostmail/usr/vmail/domain.su/admin
```

вопрос - как это сделать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, ответить на данный вопрос сам не могу - только комментарием... В данном случае вопрос был именно в том, чтобы эту самую папку прицепить к своему ящику. Оказалось, цеплять нужно не `/D1/spam/badsender/new/`, а `/D1/spam/badsender/` и делать это

```
sudo -su mailuser ln -s /D1/spam/badsender /usr/vmail/domain.su/lostmail/.badsender
```

Всё равно спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

обычно в антиспаме демоне можно указать куда кидать письма с меткой спам